# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API not accepting View Model on POST from MVC ASP.NET Core solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two solutions one is an MVC5 web app and the other is an MVC core 2.2 web app that acts as a basic web form.

I am trying to post the webform data (using a ViewModel) to the MVC5 web app API.

**The Code**

The POST method on the MVC5 web app/api

```
// POST
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] WebFormDataVM personData)
{
    // logic here
}
```

The MVC core webform (posting to the above)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PersonVM personData)
{
    var path = "api/WebForm/Post";
    var url = new Uri("http://localhost:60291/");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = url;

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, personData);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**The Issue**

When posting the `viewmodel` the `POST` method API parameter `(WebformDataVM personData)` is always `null`.

I have tried the exact same setup but using an MVC5 project/solution instead of core and it works without fail.

**What i have tried**

Posting a string instead of view model object
Removing HTTPS from the .net core project (via the project options)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could capture the request that you're sending in fiddler (or some other tool) and compare the working request vs failing request. are they actually the same?

Comment: Cheers, what is interesting is that both requests succeed however one doesn't deliver the data (shows null on the POST method) and the other does. fiddler seems to reflect this...

Comment: Can you post the Json that's being sent?

Comment: Not seeing the JSON within fiddler i'm afraid. I can see the form values within the WebForms tab.

Comment: as @GregH says, use some tool( fiddler, postman, insomnia,etc) to send a Json of your model. Use debugger to see whats your controller is sending.

Comment: @bsod_ can you post the raw versions of the working and not working requests? You're calling `PostAsJsonAsync` so it doesn't make sense to me why you would have no json data... are you sure the vm isn't null when calling it and that the code you posted here accurately reflects what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should srialize your object to json

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var url ="yourUrl" // http://localhost:60291/api/WebForm/Post
            var model=yourObject; //PersonVM  
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        }
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked, interestingly i had tried to serialize iwthin my testing and only the way you have shown has worked. Still not sure as to why it was working in a non-core project. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this solution

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PersonVM personData)
{
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60291/api/WebForm/Post");

                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("personData", personData);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

}



   [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult  Post(WebFormDataVM personData)
        {
           // code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however i am still having the same issue - null on personData at the Post method